# How to re-render graphic in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have written a conversion program (C#) that takes as inputs the state-level data for COVID-19 cases in the United States from The New York Times on GitHub and the us-states.js file from the Leaflet Interactive Choropleth Map. The program produces a JSON file that contains

```
{
 "type":"Feature",
 "id":"01",
 "properties":{
               "name":"Alabama",
               "start":"01/21/2020",
               "count":81,
               "cases":[0,0,0,...]
              },
 "geometry":{...}
},...
```

where the density of the state, in the original data, was replaced by start and count values, and the cases array. Where cases for a particular state do not start on the same date as does Washington State (01/21/2020), the missing dates cases are represented by zero. This allows the cases array to be accessed by an index that represents a specific day across all dates. Now it is possible to map the COVID-19 cases as the spread throughout the US. For the mapping, I decided to use the same Leaflet Interactive Choropleth Map software as a template (I have no experience with current mapping software so I pretty much copied the Leaflet code). The final intent is to have a setInterval timer trigger the revision to the map. The code follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- from https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/ -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>By State COVID-19 Spread</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='Leaflet-1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css' />
    <script src='Leaflet-1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='map' style='width:700px;height:500px'></div>
    <div style='display:table-cell;margin-top:100px;'>
      <button type='button' onclick='update()'>Update</button> 
      <label for='day_number' style='height:12pt;margin-left:30px;'>Day Number:</label>
      <span id='day_number' style='height:12pt; margin-left:5px;'></span>
    </div>
  <script src='cases-by-us-state.js'></script>
  <script>
    var case_index = 67;
    document.getElementById('day_number').innerHTML = case_index; 
    var maximum_cases = statesData.features[0].properties.count;
    var mapboxAccessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZ2dndXN0YWZzb24iLCJhIjoiY2s4a2RlOW42MDByYzNucGgxc2I0d2RqeCJ9.bB2UhdKKupjIXEV54N70pQ';
    var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);

    function getColor ( d ) 
      {
      // colors from https://colorbrewer2.org
      return d > 10000 ? '#99000d' :
             d > 5000  ? '#cb181d' :
             d > 2000  ? '#ef3b2c' :
             d > 1000  ? '#fb6a4a' :
             d > 500   ? '#fc9272' :
             d > 200   ? '#fcbba1' :
             d > 100   ? '#fee0d2' :
                         '#fff5f0';
      }

    function style ( feature ) 
      {

      return {
        fillColor: getColor ( feature.properties.cases[case_index] ),
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'black',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
        };
      }

    L.tileLayer ( 
      'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=' + mapboxAccessToken, 
        {
        id: 'us_states_cases',
        attribution: '<a https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-dataMap>NY Times</a>',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1
        } ).addTo ( map );

    L.geoJson ( statesData, { style: style } ).addTo ( map );

    function update ( )
      {
      if ( case_index < ( maximum_cases - 1 ) )
        {
        case_index++; 
        }
      else 
        {
        case_index = 0;
        }
      document.getElementById('day_number').innerHTML = case_index; 
      map.invalidateSize()
      }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My problem occurs in the update function. It doesn't update the graphic! Whenever the Update button is clicked, the Day Number increments but the graphic for the data for that day number does not paint. Thoughts?

Stay Safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rerun the geojson:

```
  L.tileLayer ( 
      'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=' + mapboxAccessToken, 
        {
        id: 'us_states_cases',
        attribution: '<a https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-dataMap>NY Times</a>',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1
        } ).addTo ( map );

var data = L.geoJson ( statesData, { style: style } ).addTo ( map );


function update ( ){
      if ( case_index < ( maximum_cases - 1 ) )
        {
        case_index++; 
        }
      else 
        {
        case_index = 0;
        }
      document.getElementById('day_number').innerHTML = case_index; 

      data.removeFrom(map) // To remove the layers
      data = L.geoJson ( statesData, { style: style } ).addTo ( map );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works just fine.